# Como fazer operações com colunas onde se dá apelidos?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte consulta hipotética ao banco:

```
SELECT dinheiro_na_carteira, 
(SELECT sum(despesas_pagas_carteira) FROM DESPESAS WHERE id = X ) as despesas 
FROM RECEITAS
WHERE dinheiro_na_carteira - despesas > 0
```

Ao tentar fazer essa consulta ele retorna o seguinte erro:

> [Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Nome de coluna inválido

Alguém pode me dar uma sugestão como posso resolver essa situação? Não sei nem o que procurar para resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use uma `subconsulta` correlacionada.

Uma `subconsulta` **correlacionada** é uma `subconsulta` que não pode ser executada independentemente da consulta externa. A ordem das operações em uma `subconsulta` correlacionada funciona assim:

1. Uma linha é processada na consulta externa.
2. Então, para essa linha específica na consulta externa a `subconsulta` é executada.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE DESPESAS
(
  id INT,
  dinheiro_na_carteira INT,
  despesas_pagas_carteira INT
);

INSERT INTO DESPESAS(id,dinheiro_na_carteira,despesas_pagas_carteira)
VALUES (1,10,5),(1,15,26);

SELECT id
    ,dinheiro_na_carteira
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,dinheiro_na_carteira
        ,sum(despesas_pagas_carteira) total
    FROM DESPESAS
    WHERE id = 1
    GROUP BY id,dinheiro_na_carteira
    ) AS despesas
WHERE dinheiro_na_carteira - total > 0
```

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/929750/1)

Comment: Eu entendi sua solução. obrigado!

Comment: @DavidVinicius Eu aprendi sobre essa `subQuery` aqui: [SQL: Table Transformation](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/sql-table-transformation).